# How to count and compare amount of regex matches

Tags: sumologic

I want to use Sumo Logic to count how often different APIs are called. I want to have a table with API call name and value. My current query is like this:

```
_sourceCategory="my_category"
| parse regex "GET.+443 (?<getUserByUserId>/user/v1/)\d+" nodrop
| parse regex "GET.+443 (?<getUserByUserNumber>/user/v1/userNumber)\d+" 
| count by getUserByUserId, getUserByUserNumber
```

This gets correct values but they go to different columns. When I have more variables, table becomes very wide and hard to read.

Comment: Answering my own question because I figured it out: I need to use same group name for all rexexes. Like this: _sourceCategory="my_category" | parse regex "GET.+443 (?<endpoint>/user/v1/)\d+" nodrop | parse regex "GET.+443 (?<endpoint>/user/v1/userNumber)\d+" | count by endpoint

Comment: You can add your answer as a properly posted answer if you like, then mark it as the accepted one. The reason I wanted to let you know was that it makes the question show up as having a green accepted answer in searches and more people can find it easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I need to use same group name for all rexexes. Like this:

```
_sourceCategory="my_category"
| parse regex "GET.+443 (?<endpoint>/user/v1/)\d+" nodrop
| parse regex "GET.+443 (?<endpoint>/user/v1/userNumber)\d+"
| count by endpoint
```